# Is "That is to say" used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, punctuation

> In many situations, applicants are checked for criminal convictions to
> reduce the risks of potential hazards. That is to say, employers tend
> to hire someone without any criminal background.

I need to know if I have used the phrase "That is to say" correctly.

1. Is the meaning correct? I wanted to add extra information to what I'd already said.
2. Is the punctuation correct? In dictionaries, I have seen this phrase comes between commas.

Comment: "risks of potential hazards" is redundant, because risks **are** hazards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the phrase "That is to say" is used correctly.  The phrase is normally used to mean: [in other words; or, to clarify or explain more clearly](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that+is+to+say).  That includes adding small bits of additional information on the tail end of something else as you have indicated as trying to achieve.

For [example](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that-is-to-say):

> Our friends, **that is to say** our son's friends, will meet us at the airport.

"Our son's friends" is information that wasn't given before and is used to provide clarification.  A-OK, similar to how you've used it.

---

Regarding punctuation:

Here's an [example](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/17/opinion/belarus-europes-last-dictatorship.html) without commas, provided by [Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/that+is+to+say).  This is more common.  The phrase usually appears at the beginning of a sentence like you have used it:

> …just try to imagine yourself in their shoes. **That is to say**, in their cells.

This [example](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/04/magazine/the-ethicist-caveat-vendor.html) that shows how the phrase may be put between commas.

> You could… give them a big song and dance about all the great things happening in your company… You could, **that is to say**, lie.

This may not be the greatest example, because this is the same as saying:

> That is to say, you could lie.

Hope this helps.